# How can I receive multiple inputs using python-telegram-bot and save them in different variables to be sent in a JSON request?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I need to receive two inputs from the user. For instance:

First question example:

```
await bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="What is your name?")
```

Second question example :

```
await bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="How old are you?")
```

The answers from the user must be saved in two variables. The problem is that the Telegram bot API provides only the update_message function to receive inputs from the user, but it can only handle one response at a time.

Comment: Yes you can, but you'll need a damon or conversation handler.